# how to count characters overlapping on itextpdf columntext no_more_column

Tags: itext

i'm trying to put text (Chunk) to ColumnText object with longer text than can fit in that column.. function go() returns NO_MORE_COLUMN as excepted, but how i can get remaining string that is not fitting in column? i use autohyphenation on column..

code is like that:

```
PdfContentByte bait=pdfw.getDirectContent();
bait.saveState();
Chunk c=new Chunk(text, font);
HyphenationAuto h=new HyphenationAuto("fi", "FI", 2, 2);
c.setHyphenation(h);
float rowheight=1.3f*font.getSize();
c.setLineHeight(rowheight);
ColumnText ct=new ColumnText(bait); 
ct.setSimpleColumn(100, 100, 300, 300);
ct.setAlignment(com.itextpdf.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
ct.addText(c);
int ret=ct.go();
```

i tried something like adding chars to chunk and then trying go() in loop so long that NO_MORE_COLUMN happens, but that column output is not right after that..

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to make the text fit by reducing the font size? Do you want to display the part that doesn't fit elsewhere? Do you want to predict if the text will fit? `ColumnText` doesn't give you access to the content that is waiting to be rendered, but depending on what you need, there may be another approach.

Comment: yes, i want to display that extra part somewhere else.. what i need from columntext is only that autohyphenation and sizeing of column..

Comment: If you get `NO_MORE_COLUMN`, you define a new column using the `setSimpleColumn()` with other parameters and you call `go()` once more. Isn't that what you need? What goes wrong when you try that?

Comment: ok. i have to get all those columntexts to own vector where i can then put them back to another page and place.. that works. not an ideal situation because i have to get all columntext-objects to vector and handle them.. i only needed string, so this is little memory-intensive way, but still, this works for now. for that columntext class, there is needed one function more for that kind of situations.. String getRemaining() or something like that.. also that hasRemaining() would be nice..